# Decrypting MD5 in VB.NET FORM DATABASE

Tags: vb.net, encryption

I'm having trouble in decrypting may password that came from database and send to email recovery. here's the code to encrypt my password.

```
Dim des As New TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider
Dim md5 As New MD5CryptoServiceProvider

'we need to make hash function

Function md5hash(ByVal password)
    Return md5.ComputeHash(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(password))



End Function

'now we can create function by using this has

Function encrypt(ByVal strings, ByVal key)
    des.Key = md5hash(key)
    des.Mode = CipherMode.ECB

    Dim buffer = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(strings)

    Return Convert.ToBase64String(des.CreateEncryptor().TransformFinalBlock(buffer, 0, buffer.length))

End Function
```

and here it's how to encrypt

```
    Dim cs As New Functions
    Dim strText As String = newpassword.Text
    Dim bytHashedData As Byte()
    Dim encoder As New UTF8Encoding()
    Dim md5Hasher As New MD5CryptoServiceProvider
    Dim md5 As New md5
    Dim data1 As String
    data1 = md5.encrypt(newpassword.Text, "This is key")
    Dim data2 As String
    data2 = md5.encrypt(oldpassword.Text, "This is key")


    If cs.checklogin(oldpassword.Text, newpassword.Text) = False Then
        If cs.checkusername(UserName.Text) = True Then
            If cs.checkpass(data2) = True Then
                If cs.changepass(data1, UserName.Text) = False Then
                    MessageBox.Show("Password changed successfully.")
                    bytHashedData = md5Hasher.ComputeHash(encoder.GetBytes(strText & newpassword.Text))
                    UserName.Text = ""
                    oldpassword.Text = ""
                    newpassword.Text = ""
                Else
                    MessageBox.Show("Something Went wrong!")
                End If
            Else
                MessageBox.Show("Old password is incorect!")
            End If
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Username not found!")
        End If

        Else
            MessageBox.Show("We strictly comply completing all required fields.")
        End If
End Sub
```

what should I do to get the password from the database to to decrypt my password.

Comment: Firstly, please don't use MD5 for passwords. It's not safe. Ideally, don't write your own authentication code at all - use a component written by an industry expert. Secondly, MD5 is a one-way hash. There will be several values which all hash to the same result. So "decrypting" it doesn't make sense. Thirdly, it's not quite clear what you mean by "decrypting may password that came from database and send to email recovery" but if you're talking about emailing a password in plaintext, please don't. Emailing a one-off reset is one thing, but a real password... no.

Answer (score 1):

MD5 is hashing, not encryption. A large part of the reason hashing is used for this is because it's not reversible; that is, once hashed, your password is never supposed to be recovered. Only by accepting a password from a user and comparing its hash to the one you've saved should you be able to tell that it's accurate.

That said, MD5 is a very poor algorithm to use on its own, as will be noted in most comments.

Email password 'recovery' is about resetting the password; one approach is to generate a separate time-limited hash to construct a URL to send to the user that presents a password reset form. If the hash matches, use that form to accept and then hash (look into switching to bcrypt if that's an option you have) and save the new password the user provides.

Comment: is there no any other way to decrypt my password from database?

Comment: There are ways to try and crack an MD5'ed password, but that's not something I'm going to get into. The fundamental misunderstanding here is that your current passwords are not encrypted. Encryption is intentionally reversible. They are hashed, and hashes are intended to be irreversible.